# Install Python Gtk using Mac Ports

Tags: macos, installation, python, macports

I'm attempting to install the Gimp using Mac Ports on OSX 10.5.  The Gimp won't build because it requires Python 2.5 gtk.  I'm getting the following error when installing Python GTK:

```
$ sudo port install py25-gtk
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for py25-gtk
--->  Staging py25-setuptools into destroot
Error: Target org.macports.destroot returned: shell command " cd     "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_python_py25-setuptools/work/setuptools-0.6c11" && /opt/local/bin/python2.5 setup.py --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/opt/local --root=/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_python_py25-setuptools/work/destroot " returned error 1
Command output: sh: line 0: cd:     /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_python_py25-setuptools/work/setuptools-0.6c11: No such file or directory

Error: The following dependencies failed to build: py25-cairo py25-numpy py25-nose py25-setuptools
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

I'm thinking this might be related to the fact that I also have Python 2.6 installed, which I needed to do to get mercurial+svn working.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be similar to [this one](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/16741) on the MacPorts trac site. The conclusion was that it was a corrupt Python 2.5 installation and removing and reinstalling python2.5 and all py25- ports solved the problem.

Also, the [macports-users mailing list](http://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo/macports-users/) is much more active than MacPorts-related posts here at superuser.com and your problem may be better solved there (or already solved, search first).